# How to identify if onfocus event is coming from embedded iframe

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, dom-events

In the below code the `onfocus` event gets called if

[1] Click play button in youtube
[2] click outside the iframe area.

I think the focus change from current window to iframe window and this iframe window is considered as a different window.

**What I want is that `onfocus` event should not get fired when event is bubbling from a iframe within the main window.**?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
window.onfocus = function(e) {
    console.log(e)
    debugger;
}
</script>
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`onfocus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus) will never come out of an iframe, it doesn't bubble.

Comment: Can't be done. You can't access cross domain iframe due to ***same origin policy***. Check youtube docs in case perhaps they my include any postMessage events that do allow communication across windows but I rather doubt they do